# Failed to load PDF document using aws-sdk in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I have a problem when uploading pdf files to S3.

I have no problems creating pdf files using `PDFkit` and storing them locally (I can view them in my browser).

But when I try to upload them to my S3 storage, I get this error **Failed to load PDF document.** when opening a pdf in my browser. You can check it out:
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pdf-twitter-bucket/twitter/HvkH98YA0p.pdf

```
        fs.readFile('../pdf/' + fileName, 'utf8', function (err, contents) {
          const buf = new Buffer(contents, 'base64');
          // define params
          const params = {
            Bucket: 'pdf-twitter-bucket',
            Key: 'twitter/' + fileName,
            Body: buf,
            ContentType: 'application/pdf',
            ACL: 'public-read'
          };

          s3bucket.upload(params, function (err) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('error in callback');
              console.log(err);
            }
            res.end(
              'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pdf-twitter-bucket/twitter/' +
              fileName
            ); // send the link to s3
          });
        });
```

I've tried many options:
1) using `Buffeer` and not using `Buffer`
2) I have no problems uploading `.txt` files
3) I've even tried passing a string as a `Body` value

Before writing this question I've carried out a small research and found similar problems:

https://github.com/VeliovGroup/Meteor-Files/issues/406

Unfortunately, it didn't help me much...

Comment: how did you fix it? running into the same issue

Comment: @tskittles check for https://gist.github.com/sarfarazansari/59d5cf4bb3b03acf069396ca92a79b3e

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue with S3 upload. I couldn't open the PDF and it was just a few bytes in size (instead of a few KB). I think the problem was that I didn't wait for the write stream to complete.

This works for me now:

```js
document.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileName));
document.end();
document.on('end', function () {
  fs.readFile(fileName, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    s3.upload({
      Bucket: s3Bucket,
      Key: fileName,
      Body: data,
      ContentType: 'application/pdf',
      acl: 'private',
      contentDisposition: 'attachment',
      ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256'
    }, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's too late for an answer.
But am answering if someone came to this page he/she will get the right approach.

I made a git which will work perfectly in any kind of file.https://gist.github.com/sarfarazansari/59d5cf4bb3b03acf069396ca92a79b3e